# Check only string using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to check only string, not whole line. For example, my line is like this

```
"pwd requisite dcredit=-5 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 minlen=14 difok=4 retry=2"
```

I have to check `lcredit=-1` this string

Condition is :

1. If this string is same like this `lcredit=-1` we skip this
2. If the string `lcredit=2` not in `-1` then here we have to change `-1`
3. If the string is not there have to add the string end of the line.

and one more `lcredit=-1` contain any of the position in that particular line.

If I am using `lineinfile` it would be change whole line and the line string position is different. If I am using `replace`, it would only be replaced, but if not there it will not add. So any other function to satisfy my condition?

Comment: This seems like a situation where you want to either change the file format (if you can) or write a custom parser; it'd be fairly easy to do this sort of thing in Python with a split on whitespace and then a split on equal signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use regular expressions (untested):

```yaml
- name: If lcredit is specified, make sure it is -1
  lineinfile:
    regexp: "^pwd requisite(.*) lcredit=(-?\d+)(.*)"
    backrefs: yes
    line: 'pwd requisite\1 lcredit=-1\2'
    dest: /etc/pam.d/whatever

- name: If lcredit not specified, add it
  lineinfile:
    regexp: "^pwd requisite((?!.* lcredit=.*).*)"
    backrefs: yes
    line: 'pwd requisite\1 lcredit=-1'
    dest: /etc/pam.d/whatever
```

Usually I try to avoid regular expressions, especially complicated ones like the above. If you don't already know them it often doesn't pay to invest in learning them. So what I would do would be to try to find a way to work around the problem. For example, would it work to always specify the whole exact line, rather than try to be clever with moving its parts around?